# Should I learn Google Cloud Messaging or Firebase for Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following an android tutorials from Udacity which was made around 2014, on the final lesson it uses Google Cloud messaging.
(https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud853/lessons/1614738811/concepts/16346189090923#)

From the website of GCM it recommend to use Firebase.

Should I skip this lesson and Jump to another course of Udacity which focuses on Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

This depends entirely up to you. As of the moment, GCM is still being supported. However, since you're just starting to learn and try to use it, I would suggest for you to go with FCM instead.

It is also required for you to create/import a Firebase Project to generate a valid Sever Key, so that's another point to go with FCM.

The core structure is pretty much the same since FCM is built on GCM, only that FCM has some minor changes and additional features.

Plus, you get the chance to see Firebase services if you go around the docs, see the other services offered.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase is oriented more for Mobile development and GCM is still more for Web development. And using Firebase is more convenient.